# using two java files with two class compilation error

Tags: java

I am new to java, trying to learn by making mini projects right now. I have two classes and when I run my program I have this error : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Game.balance. 
Not quite sure why I am getting it and wondering if anyone knows any fixes.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mainone {



    public static void main(String[] args) {



        System.out.println("You have $1000. I hope you make good choices!");

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        Game print = new Game(1000,0,0,true);
        System.out.print(Game.operation);



}

}
```

this is the second class below (new file)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Game {

    int balance = 1000;
    int operationAmount;
    int randOperation;
    boolean ad = true;

    public Game(int b, int o, int r, boolean a) {
        balance = b;
        operationAmount = o;
        randOperation = r;
        ad = a;

    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to print ?

Comment: There is no such static field `operation` in the Game class. Then, it is obvious that you will get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
System.out.print(Game.operation);
```

change to

```java
System.out.print(print.operation);
```

In java, you can't access Object field values by Class directly. But you can access the static field by using Class.

```java
public class Game {

    public static String ABC = "1"; // can access by Game.ABC
    int balance = 1000;
    int operationAmount;
    int randOperation;
    boolean ad = true;

    public Game(int b, int o, int r, boolean a) {
        balance = b;
        operationAmount = o;
        randOperation = r;
        ad = a;

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("You have $1000. I hope you make good choices!");

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        Game print = new Game(1000,0,0,true);
        System.out.print(Game.ABC); // here you can access the static field
}
```

Comment: Also keep in mind ```operation``` is not an attribute of ```Game```

Comment: yes I realized that error and that makes sense to me. For some reason I get another error " operation cannot be resolved or is not a field" .

Comment: You didn't post the code about `operation` in the Game class, is it a method?If it is, you need to call the method by `print.opertion()`.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call Game.operation. Instead of this try print.operation.

I assume operation is function in class Game.

Comment: now i get this error " operation cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Answer (score 0):

Here the state is managed by the print object of Game class.

Please call `System.out.print(print.operation);`